# Golang syntax error: unexpected EOF while writing to a file

Tags: file-io, go

Getting a `syntax error: unexpected EOF` on the last line of code which is a bracket. It has something to do with File IO because the JSON code worked before I added that in

```
b, err := json.Marshal(gfjson)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)

    filename := ".gfjson"

    f, err := os.Create(filename)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // close file on exit and check for returned error
    defer func() {
        if err := f.Close(); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }()


    if _, err := f.Write(b); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "GFJSON file successfully created.\n")
}
```

Comment: you have an extra closing brace there with no matching open brace anywhere in your code sample. Either you didn't show us all the code or that brace doesn't belong there.

Comment: oh sorry yeah I didn't show all the code, the brace is there. Edit actually there is a missing brace (doh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a closing bracket on line 4 after the panic.

```
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Your code actually compiles fine for me, but this is because you have a random closing brace at the end balancing it out. I assume from you indentations that the close brace at the end is then end of your function and only the panic should be part of the if statement.